# How to compare variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm begginer in linux console; I want to create `if` statement with integer variables

```
if[$x= [$#-2]]
```

But console receive if `can't find this statment if[1 = [5-2]]`
Please help me and correct my statement.

Comment: Please learn at least this from your question: bash (and other shells) is very whitespace sensitive -- lines are split into tokens with whitespace. The `if` command needs a space between it and its conditional command. `[` is a *command* in the shell, not just syntax. The `=` operator needs spaces around it. When in doubt, use spaces. Further documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need Arithmetic Expansion: `$((expression))`

```
if [ $x = $(($# - 2)) ]; then
# ^ ^  ^ ^           ^ spaces are mandatory
```

Comment: @jan345 Karoly not only mentions the arith expansion but also the spaces. You need the spaces with all if-statements!

Answer (score 0):

To start `$#` is the number of parameters passed to the bash script

`./bash_script 1 2 3`

`$#` auto-magically populates to 3. I hope you know this already.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=1
#If you are trying to compare `$x` with the value of the expression `$# - 2` below is how you do it :
if (( $x == $# - 2 ))
then
echo "Some Message"
fi
#If you are trying to check the assignment to `$x was successful below is how you do it :
if (( x = $# - 2 ))
then
echo "Some Message"
fi
```

The second condition is almost always true, but the first can be false.
Below are the results of my test runs :

```
#Here the both ifs returned true
sjsam@WorkBox ~/test
$ ./testmath1 1 2 3 
Some Message
Some Message
#Here the first if returned false because we passed 4 parameters
sjsam@WorkBox ~/test 
$ ./testmath1 1 2 3 4
Some Message
```

Comment: @jan345 : Here the first part is for comparison. Did you try it?